# How can I aggregate a Likes collection to it's Posts collection in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Scenario:** We have an application with Posts collection and a Likes collection with the postId and customerId associated to it. The schema of both these collections are as defined below:

```js
// Post Schema 
let postSchema = new Schema({
  user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user"},
  text: {type: String},
  likeCount: {type: Number}
)}


// Like Schema
let likeSchema = newSchema({
  post: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "post"},
  user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "user"},
})
```

**Case:** I will be fetching posts (with pagination). But, I also want to send an indicator that says if the user has already liked this post or not.

**Questions:**

1. What would be the best way to fetch a set of articles with an added indicator (or a new key) that states if it is liked by the existing user. (I will have the userId at the time of executing the query).
2. Would aggregation be a good choice? If yes, How can I aggregate it? Really confused with the pipeline.
3. If not aggregation, what else could be the best possible ways to map if the user has liked a post or not?

**Additional Details**: We're using Node.Js on server side and we will be indexing the likes collection.

Comment: could you provide sample data and your expected out put ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "likes", // likes collection name
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "user",
      as: "user",
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      isLiked: { ifNull: ["$user", false] },
    },
  },
  {
    $skip: pageNumber > 1 ? (pageNumber - 1) * nPerPage : 0,
  },
  {
    $limit: nPerPage,
  },
]);
```

pageNumber in number of page
nPerPage is number of doc in each page

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your response, but this is now what I'm expecting. Just for some detailed clarity, the user in the Post is the author of the post, and the user in the likes collection can be any customer (including the author).  If I have any customer logged in, I'll have their userId, So I want to pull the posts (just as you have mentioned here) and then also check, if the customer has liked any of the post. If yes, send the isLiked key (just like what you have added)  as true.

Comment: do you have any collection for users ?

Comment: Yes, We also have a user collection (holding all user's details).

Comment: I update my answer , let me explain , I search in users collection and populate like by user id if the is null value for user key it will add isLike to false

Comment: Hi, Sorry to continuing this, but I'm not expecting a list of users. I want to pull out a list of posts. Say I'm logged in as a customer and want to fetch a list of posts, In such case the API should return me a list of posts, with an additional flag of isLiked, This flag shows if the customer has previously liked the post or not. Or to be clear, if the like schema has an entry of the post and customer's user ID or not.

Comment: Can i find with likecount field?

Comment: Good question :D  but I don''t think that will be possible, I'll have to load the latest posts from the Post Collection.